# Importing synaptics settings

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

I've got a Samsung Series 5 Chromebook which I've installed Ubuntu on. In Chrome OS the clickpad is working great but in ubuntu it hasn't got the same settings so I'm having problems with selcting text. I managed to find the setting in Chrome OS, it's 120 about lines of settings looking like this:

```
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (131):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (133): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (265): -1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (266):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (267):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (268):    10.000000
    Device Node (250):  "/dev/input/event6"
```

Now I would like to import these settings to Ubuntu. Is that possible?

Comment: Which version of ubuntu have you installed on your Chromebook? If you don't know, do you still have the instructions you were following?